# What is the difference between $a = $(Read-Host) and $a = (Read-Host)?

Tags: powershell

I have to review some scripts what my Ex-Colleague left behind and I am very curious why he is using `$a = $(Read-Host -Prompt "Write something")` in the Parameters section rather than `$a = (Read-Host -Prompt "Write something")`.

I have tested it in a single script but haven't seen any difference so far.
I have searched thru the google and StackOverFlow but haven't find any clue so far what could be the difference.
Maybe my searching methods are bad.

Comment: `$()` is the subexpression operator that will turn the result of a statement into an expression. For `Read-Host`, there is no difference, because the output of a cmdlet can be used directly as an expression. But something like `1 + (if ($true) { 1 } else { 2 })` will not parse, you must use `1 + $(if ($true) { 1 } else { 2 })`. I cannot immediately think of a scenario where you would have to use `$()` when a cmdlet is involved, but I won't exclude the possibility that there is one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting from [Keith Hill's blog](https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/11/24/effective-powershell-item-10-understanding-powershell-parsing-modes/):

> *What’s the difference between grouping expressions (), subexpressions $() and array subexpressions @()?*  A grouping expression can contain just a single statement.  A subexpression can contain multiple semicolon separated statements.  The output of each statement contributes to the output of the subexpression.  An array subexpression behaves just like a subexpression except that it guarantees that the output will be an array.  The two cases where this makes a difference are 1) there is no output at all so the result will be an empy array and 2) the result is a scalar value so the result will be a single element array containg the scalar value.  If the output is already an array then the use of an array subexpession will have no affect on the output i.e. array subexpressions do not wrap arrays inside of another array.

Silly example:

```
$a = (Read-Host -Prompt 'something'; echo 'foo')
$b = $(Read-Host -Prompt 'something'; echo 'foo')
```

The first statement (with the grouping expression) will throw an error, because you cannot have multiple statements in a grouping expression. The second statement will work and append a line "foo" to the text entered via `Read-Host`.

In your example scenario (`$a = (Read-Host -Prompt 'something')` vs. `$a = $(Read-Host -Prompt 'something')`) it doesn't make any difference. More precisely, you shouldn't use either grouping expression or subexpression operator in that scenario, because they have no purpose there.

Answer (score 2):

`$()` is for evaluating subexpressions in strings. It does nothing here.

You don't need () around read-host either, you can simply use `$a = Read-Host -Prompt 'your input here'`

(`-Prompt` needs a string as parameter).

Comment: My teacher told me that just in case, if I use a command as the Parameters value, I should put it in ().
And would be any case when the $() could count in the script some times later? Which is the better one to use?

Comment: Good points, but note that while `$(…)` is _typically_ used inside double-quoted strings, it can be used in other contexts too; to borrow the sample command from Jeroen Mostert' comment on the question: `1 + $(if ($true) { 1 } else { 2 })`